# UV mapping - Unwrap greyed out

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm using Blender 2.71.

After adding armatures to my model I cannot unwrap or show a uv map. I've done it before on a different model and with the same one. But now I cannot unwrap it at all and the texture won't even show. When selecting all in edit mode the option to unwrap is greyed out.

I was following this tutorial to add armatures if this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPbSGUPj72w

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any faces in your model.

Comment: Could you post a .blend please?

Comment: Thanks gandalf3. Having no faces was the problem. Just preesing F solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have no faces.

To add faces, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In edit Mode press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything if any faces were hidden. If it doesn't work, select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, next Press <kbd>F</kbd>.

Also check if there are any double vertices, select all and run <kbd>W</kbd> > Remove Doubles

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.